# A word that means unable to die AND unable to be killed?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that means unable to die AND unable to be killed? so immortal would not work in this case because an immortal person can be killed and invincible would not work because you can still die of natural causes. Is there a word that works for both?

Comment: Why do you think an immortal person can be killed?

Comment: The definition of "immortal" depends on where it is used. "Standard" English does not distinguish between the two "disabilities", calling both immortal, but several fictional or mythological works do distinguish between the two states. Also note, "invincible" does not mean "unable to die from natural causes". "Invincible" means "cannot be defeated". A chess grandmaster could be "invincible", but could and probably would still die of natural causes.

Comment: Michael Harvey- there are numerous example in mythology where an immoral god is killed. For example: Osiris is killed by Set, Balder is killed by Loki and many Norse gods die in Ragnarok. This is also something from another page on here similar to this conversation: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85252/can-immortal-be-used-to-describe-someone-that-lives-forever-yet-can-be-destro/85272

Comment: Thank you sharur, I do understand that it does depend on how it is being used, I am looking for a word that you don't have to question the meaning.

Comment: Mythology _isn't real_. The dictionary definition of "immortal" is, typically, "not subject to death". There is no such thing as a immortal person or creature. Thus, such things as whether they can be killed by silver bullets, splinters of the True Cross, holy water, beheading, or whatever, are issues of fiction, and it is hardly surprising that "one word" is unlikely to be forthcoming.

Comment: In some genres of fiction, immortal beings can be killed. The word 'eternal' may better give you what you want ... but the answer is not clear-cut.

Comment: Undying is also good

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.dictionary.com:

> immortal:
>
> not mortal; not liable or subject to death; undying
>
> remembered or celebrated through all time:
>
> not liable to perish or decay; imperishable; everlasting.